# Provider pool size for health insurance plan

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

I am selecting health insurance. My goal is a low premium/high deductible plan, but with a large selection of providers. In other words, if I have a serious medical problem, I would like the ability to choose from a wide array of doctors in order to get the best care. However, I can find no way of evaluating (1) the provider pool per plan for my current insurance company nor (2) the provider pool per plan for competing insurance companies. Are provider lists published anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for all healthcare  insurance companies but whenever I have been in the market for a plan, the company's web site offered a list of providers.  It may take a little searching and a bit of downloading but I've always been able to compare coverage, deductibles, providers, etc. across various plans.